# Error pushing to Github

Tags: git, github, push

After doing `git init`, `git add .`, and `git commit`,  pushing to Github gives this error:

```
HOLLYs-MacBook-Pro-2:Thankful dylanknight$ git push origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Dknight2017/thankful.app.git/' not found
HOLLYs-MacBook-Pro-2:Thankful dylanknight$
```

I have pulled from the repository, but when I try to push to Github, I consistently get this error. How do I properly connect to my remote repository?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not in the right directory. When you clone your repo, you should get a folder called `thankful-app`. If you `cd` into that directory and do `ls -la` you should see a `.git` folder.

Once you're in that location, try and do a git push.

I tried to push to it, and got `Permission denied` which is to be expected.